# Plotting Sentinel-2 Level-2A Scene Classification in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, sentinel-2

I am interested to visualize the result of Scene Classification (SC) that is automatically performed during the production of level-2A products. I am using GEE.

I have read this [page](https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/technical-guides/sentinel-2-msi/level-2a/algorithm-overview#:%7E:text=of%20the%20algorithms.-,Scene%20Classification%20(SC),soils%2Fdeserts%2C%20water%20and%20snow) and this [page](https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/processing-levels/level-2) and I can see that there are 23 bands inside each sentine-2 level-2A product. I can see that half of these are "original" Bands of S2 and the rest are the "products" of S2 preprocessing algorithm.

What I can not figure out is how to combine the information of these separate layers/bands in order to visualize a classification map that represents the spatial distribution of the mentioned 12 groups (4 different clouds etc.)

In addition if there are information of min/max bounding values of each layer/band and its interpretation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to select the scl band, and then assign a palette to a visualization of a single band raster with values between 1 and 11.

These things look like `.select('scl')` either on an image or the image collection and visualization parameters will be `{min:1, max:11, palette:['ff0004','868686','774b0a','10d22c','ffff52','0000ff','818181','c0c0c0','f1f1f1','bac5eb','52fff9']}`

Remember that within EE you can type the name of the dataset into the search box at the top and quickly access the relevant collection/imagery details.

Comment: Thanks. You are right the SCL band contains integer values in the range [0,11] which represent classes. I was confused a bit by the information provided in this page where the intensity range of SCL band is said to be in the range [0,255].   https://docs.digitalearthafrica.org/en/latest/data_specs/Sentinel-2_Level-2A_specs.html